# materialize dropdown doesn't work in dynamically created card

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dropdown, materialize

The materialize dropdown example works with no problem if placed in the client html file and initialized with jquery with:

```
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
    }
  );
```

When placed inside a materialize card inside a dynamically created card with angularjs, it fails to work. The dropdown button is there but it doesn't function.

The jquery version is jquery.min.js from the latest file version which might be the problem but no idea what to modify it to.

Comment: While creating the dropdown dynamically. You have to call `$('your-element').dropdown();` funtion. Then only it'll work.

Comment: Sarath - I've added `$(document).ready(function(){...}` but that doesn't help. What do you mean call the `.dropdown` function? I wrote in the post that I've done that. Tnx.

Comment: that's not like that. You already called that `$(document).ready(function(){...}` but I'm telling you to declare once again while creating the element.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to initialize the dropdown inside your loop.
i'm using jquery and i place this inside

```
$.each(data,function(key,val){
 //dropdown initialize
 $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, 
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'left' 
    });
});
```